# HTML Hover Events not Passing Through

Tags: html, z-index

I'm having a weird issue with HTML. I've confirmed that I have no negative Z indexes. Also, it doesn't look like there's anything over the elements with higher Z indexes.

It's a lot of code, so I don't know really how to grab it out for a jQuery.

I posted this here: [Example Site](http://icefraud.herokuapp.com/) - try hovering over the green or red thumbs. They *should* change color when hovered over, as just an example. What is occluding them?

Comment: umm, don't want to sound naive, but did you try sprites? This is weird, also when I try to inspect any thing on your page, including that picture of someone which is in a tile, and the text besides that, the <html> tag is getting highlighted.

Comment: @AnujKaithwas I noticed this as well, but I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: did you try removing all the `"pointer-events"`

Comment: try removing all the `"pointer-events"`, that changed the icon,  slightly bigger, right?

Comment: This is the culprit: `header * {
pointer-events: none;
z-index: 1;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have read [**this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events), but still,

CSS pointer events actually makes that element non-clickable, which means whatever you do with mouse, won't happen, be it hover, click, right-click, et al.

I tried removing the `pointer-events` in the web-inspector and that allowed me to select the text and also do a 'hover' on the thumb icons.[image: vague example]

The blackish part that you see in the second image is the selected text after removing the `pointer-events` and the `<span>` that is highlighted happened after doing a right click on the span.

[image]

Comment: It's funny, I added those AFTER I started experiencing the error. I guess afterwards, **I removed all of the negative Z indexes from ALL of the code**, which really fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianStewart, as far as I know, z-index aren't of that much importance unless you want cool transitions and animations in your website. You can make really simple and attractive websites without using `z-index` though, Google and Facebook are some examples. :)

Comment: Google and facebook have no z-index anywhere? hard to believe

Comment: @ChristianStewart, not anywhere, they have it somewhere, but not everywhere.